# Creating Test for a sealed trait in scala

Tags: testing, playframework-2.0, scalatest, traits, sealed

I have a sealed trait for which I want to write tests. However it is not possible to create an object of this sealed trait within the test class. How is it possible to test in such case.

```
Myclass.scala

sealed trait BaseTrait{
  def myFunct = //an implemented function
}

case class SecondClass extends BaseTrait {
  // This class I can test
  // ...
}

MyclassTest.Scala
class MyclassTest extends WordSpec with MustMatchers{

 //Here I want to write a test case for the function within the sealed trait

}
```

I am working on a project with Play Framework 2.3.6 and Scala and using ScalaTestPlus for testing.

Answer (score 1):

That may not be possible. Your best bet is to instantiate the simplest class that extends that trait and test it.